# going insane with a missing date in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I am loading some csv data you can grab at https://pastebin.com/CtKbHKee

The code loading it is:

```
hourly_data = pd.read_csv('../data/hourly.csv', parse_dates=True, date_parser=date_parse, index_col=0, header=0)
```

and the date parser is:

```
def date_parse(time_in_secs):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs)).replace(minute=0, second=0)
```

for some reason, the record from March 28, 2018 at 2:00 is not present!

it is in the CSV, I can see it in excel, but in pandas, it is not there.

```
d = datetime(2018, 3, 25, 1, 0, 0)
k = hourly_data.loc[d]
```

will work, but

```
d = datetime(2018, 3, 25, 2, 0, 0)
k = hourly_data.loc[d]
```

will not find a record, however

```
d = datetime(2018, 3, 25, 3, 0, 0)
k = hourly_data.loc[d]
```

does find a record...

I looked for non printable characters in the excel file, converted it to xslx, back to csv, etc... but it looks like something doesn't work with that date.

I checked the timestamp for that row and it's fine:

[image]

there has to be some very simple obvious answer, but I really don't see it!

any help would be awesome because I'm running out of ideas

(it's not the conversion to float when parsing the date btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using the `datetime` library, which leads to timezone issues if you aren't locally UTC complaint.

Use pandas to parse the dates after the fact:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data/hourly.csv', index_col=0, header=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
```

Or if you still want to use a `date_parser`

```
def date_parse(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s')

df = pd.read_csv('../data/hourly.csv', index_col=0, header=0, date_parser=date_parse)
```

---

```
                        humandate    open    high     low   close     volume         spot
date                                                                                     
2018-03-24 00:00:00  24/3/18 0:00  8921.0  8969.5  8863.0  8906.0  179387630  8914.754995
2018-03-24 01:00:00  24/3/18 1:00  8906.5  8912.0  8849.5  8850.0   81666439  8881.545110
2018-03-24 02:00:00  24/3/18 2:00  8850.0  8903.0  8826.5  8889.0   97835639  8866.931205
2018-03-24 03:00:00  24/3/18 3:00  8889.0  8905.5  8862.0  8879.5   52257288  8883.475490
2018-03-24 04:00:00  24/3/18 4:00  8879.5  8955.0  8870.0  8946.5   77400962  8914.647312
```

Answer (score 2):

DST, my friend.
Spring forward, so my guess is that the library turns the `time_in_secs` into 3 am.

Check what happens if you input `time_in_secs-1` or `time_in_secs+1`, to confirm.

Timezones and DST are a pain in the ass for every programmer...

Comment: ahh yes, I didn't think of that at all; will try and report!

Comment: ok, I did some tests: when I move the record by one second, the problem is still there at the same date. You could be right that it is the problem and the issue could be on the query side, and not on the parsing side.

Comment: I just checked, March 25 is the date where the switch happened in 2018. So, most probably DST issues. Maybe the record actually doesn't exist in the data because on that day 2am=3am